# how to redirect output to a log file without tee? normal redirection is not working

Tags: command-line, log, redirect, tee

why not use tee? because the terminal rendering of the output makes the application run slower.

for some reason, this is not working:

```
application 2>&1 >"$logFile"
```

the output keeps going to terminal..

Comment: May be, tee has some options to suppress output?

Comment: Which application? It might be doing something screwy like writing to `/dev/tty` directly, but there's no way to know without knowing which program it is.

Comment: And it is not clear what do you try to achieve. I just made the command `echo ping | tee > /dev/null` and it did not show anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have redirected `stderr` to `stdout` (the terminal), then you've redirected `stdout` to a file. In conclusion, you haven't redirected `stderr` to the file:

1. `stderr -> stdout`, `stderr` goes to the terminal.
2. `stdout -> $logfile`, `stdout` goes to the `$logfile`.

Try using the following:

```
application >"$logfile" 2>&1
```

Notice the order matters:

1. `stdout -> $logfile`, `stdout` goes to `$logfile`.
2. `stderr -> stdout -> $logfile`, `stderr` goes to `stdout` which is the same as `$logfile`.

Comment: omg, worked thx! I found this to work too `application 2>&1 |cat >"$logfile"`, and also this `script -c "/path/prog" /path/log.txt`